# How to prefix match a doc value -> search term in lucene search engines like Solr, ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

We have a need to prefix match from the `<document value> -> <search term>`. Reverse is possible in Solr, ElasticSearch which is `<search term> -> <document value>`

Example:

```
Search term -> "traveling the world"
Document field value -> "travel"
```

Not sure how to prefix match or fuzzy this query so we can get this document result.

Prefix match works like this `"travel*"`

Search term -> `"travel"`

Document field value -> `"traveling the world"`

Comment: try using the stemmer filter factory...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PorterStemFilterFactory in your field definition.

```
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
```

Your definition may look like :

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory "/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Here is the input and output would be :

**In:** "jump jumping jumped"

**Tokenizer to Filter:** "jump", "jumping", "jumped"

**Out:** "jump", "jump", "jump"

There is another alternative to it known as solr.KStemFilterFactory which is less aggressive.

I mean in short you can have a field type definition for your field as below.

```
<fieldType name="StemmerFieldTypeDef" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> 
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

With this definition for your fields it is decided that how to store the text while indexing and what text to query while querying.

The tokenizers and filters mutate your original text as per your field definition.

For example if your indexing the word "Travelling", it would indexed as "travel", and hence when your search with word "travel" it will match and you get the records in the result.

Its vice versa as well. Like if you have indexing text as "Travel" then it would be indexed as per the field definition as "travel". Here if you search text is "Travelling" then as per the fields definition it is searched as "travel". Hence as match found.

To learn and get a good understanding of this analysis, please check the solr analysis page.

In the above example the In, Out are the example of what is the input to the field and depending on the field type applied for the field you will have the output.

Comment: Thanks but can you point out how it will help in the example. Say "travel" is in solr doc and I need a prefix type search when user search term is "traveling the world". Also not sure what this In and Out means. Is it that when input field has "jump jumping jumped", porter stemmer will index "jump" with 3 count occurence? Is there a way to play with porter stemmer logic on english words? Like "traveling" -> "travel" is taken care already?

Comment: @RagingBull, I have modified the answer with more details. I hope it clears all your questions.